# How do I make custom URLs using django?

Tags: python, django, url

Right now my urls.py file looks like so:

```
re_path(r'^product-offers/(?P<product_item_id>[-\w]+)$', views.ProductOffersListView.as_view(),
```

This takes a user to the page: www.shop.com/product/1234

However, is there any way to display the URL with the title (even if that URL doesn't change the dispatching). I want the URL to look like this:

www.shop.com/product/1234/toy-truck

The "toy-truck" part doesn't have to do anything, but it looks professional and would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a slug to your model

> Slug is a newspaper term. A slug is a short label for something, containing only letters, numbers, underscores or hyphens. They’re generally used in URLs

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#slugfield

Then add it to the url and pass it together with the item id when you call the url

`re_path(r'^product-offers/(?P<product_item_id>[0-9]+/(?P<product_item_slug>[\w-]+)/$`

Comment: I'm still a bit lost when generating the url. Something like this?

{% url 'site:product-offer' product_item_id=item.id product_item_slug=item.title %}

Comment: Yep, though you might want to consider making a new field for the slug, as those are short labels very usable for urls, whereas a generic title field might give complications like spaces and long titles that make the url unreadable or at least very difficult to read (from a human perspective)